# How to remove Last 10 digit random characters From URL with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've done a lot of searching and can't find out exactly how to do this. I have no experience

Need to convert

```
http://www.songspkay.com/album/goutham-nanda-VGnqhEIY78
```

to

```
http://www.songspkay.com/album/goutham-nanda
```

For particularly album

Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1):

Rewriterule could look like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-[A-Za-z0-9]{10}$  $1 [L,R=301]
```

Depending on the purpose, the R=301 could be left out.

if the string is not always 10 characters long: "{10}" could also be "+"